# scroll bar for 100% height div

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I've managed to create this, it's the height of the page but I'm trying to get it to scroll rather than stretch forever downwards

[image]

css for .leftnavdiv

```
.leftnavdiv {
    padding-top: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    _position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    _top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop));
    left: 0px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    a:link color:#FF0000;     
    a:visited color:#00FF00;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="leftnavdiv">
            <div>
                <table style="height:100%;">
                    <tr style="height:100%;">
                        <td valign="top" style="height:100%;">
                            <div id="makebtnset" style="height:100%; overflow-y: scroll;">
                                <?php
                                //code removed
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

Comment: You have set the height to 100% of the page, and as the content increases you are making the page bigger. This is correct. You should set a fixed height in pixels

Comment: even if I set leftnavdiv to a fixed height the contents still stretch past it. I probably should have explained that there are two other columns in the table and I want them to be individually scrollable hence the overflow-y: scroll; on makebtnset rather than leftnavdiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget height: 100%, you can use:

```
.leftnavdiv {
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: auto;
   padding: 0;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: yea I'm really liking top, left, bottom, and right values. I must have been looking at old school stuff. got it fixed some time ago but appreciate the answer :)